# Next steps for debugging redirect uri mismatch?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm currently trying to use the Youtube Data API to gather transcripts from videos posted on my site. This requires me to implement OAuth2, which I have done up to the point of exchanging the access code for the access token. When I make a request to Google to get the token, I'm getting a redirect_uri_mismatch error.

I have tried copying and pasting the redirect uri from the console into my code multiple times and double checking to make sure it matches exactly, but it still says the redirect uri doesn't match those that have been registered already. So, I thought it might have mistyped something around the uri, or that the puncutation might need to be embedded, so I tried performing the request in Postman, where those factors would be accounted for, again, copying and pasting from the console, and still no luck. From there, I thought it would either be the browser I was using or that it would just take time for the uri to update. I was getting the same error after clearing my browser cache, and also on Safari, and it's been over a day now since I changed the redirect_uri in the console.

Do you have any idea what the issue might be or where I might go from here, in terms of debugging?
Here is the redirect uri exactly as it appears in the Google Cloud console:
https://dotxav.ownsocial.io/wp-json/youtube/youtube-oauth2-token

Here is a segment of my code

```
$ch = curl_init();
$client_secret = $GLOBALS\['client_secret'\];
$client_id = $GLOBALS\['client_id'\];
$redirect_uri = "https://dotxav.ownsocial.io/wp-json/youtube/youtube-oauth2-token";
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
'grant_type' =\> 'authorization_code',
'code' =\> $code,
'client_id' =\> $client_id,
'client_secret' =\> $client_secret,
'redirect_uri' =\> $redirect_uri
)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Try checking this https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ?si=YkmV5JAoDu9yUst9

Comment: Hello, I tried copying and pasting from the error message into the list of authorized redirect uri. It told me that duplicate redirect uris are not allowed, which tells me that uri from my code and the uri I entered into the Cloud console are exactly the same. What else can I do?